# Strange OpenCV Distance Transform Results

Tags: c, ubuntu, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to run a distance transform on a thresholded binary image in
order to assist anomaly detection (my hope is that I can detect large
changes around the edges of the object), however for some reason, upon
running my Distance Transform script, I'm getting a strange banding type of
effect. I tested something similar in the Distance Transform demo script in
the samples directory, with the same results. One possible reason I came up
with was that the distance was going beyond the 0-255 scale and therefore
essentially being modulus'ed to keep it within the boundaries. Has anyone
had any experience with this that could advise?
[I have posted images and code on my blog if that helps](http://www.phatgfx.co.uk/blog/?p=59)
Thanks in advance,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way to test your theory: try with a grey scale image that's muted (all values v --> 128+(v-128)/32 or something) and see if that makes the bands much wider or eliminates them completely.

It's always a good idea to nail down what the problem is first, and *then* try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the scale in a similar way to your advise and that fixed it! Somehow I missed the cvConvertScale line with a factor of 5000 - decreasing that did exactly as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the code, but I'd like to point out that the [expected result](http://www.phatgfx.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/disttrans_correct-website.png) on your blog is probably incorrect as well: look at the sharp black-gray border in the bottom part of the large object: it should not be there, as the maximum difference between two adjacent pixels should be 1.